# Counting with nested aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have been trying to group and count registration collection data for a stats page, as well as to make for dynamic registration, but I can't get it to count for more than one grouping.
Sample registration collection data:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58ec60078cc818505fb75ace"),
        "event" : "Women's BB",
        "day" : "Saturday",
        "group" : "nonpro",
        "division" : "Women's",
        "level" : "BB"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58ec60078cc818505fb75acf"),
        "event" : "Coed BB",
        "day" : "Sunday",
        "group" : "nonpro",
        "division" : "Coed",
        "level" : "BB"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58ec60098cc818505fb75ad0"),
        "event" : "Men's BB",
        "day" : "Saturday",
        "group" : "nonpro",
        "division" : "Men's",
        "level" : "BB"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58ec60168cc818505fb75ad1"),
        "event" : "Men's B",
        "day" : "Saturday",
        "group" : "nonpro",
        "division" : "Men's",
        "level" : "B"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58ec60178cc818505fb75ad2"),
        "event" : "Women's Open",
        "day" : "Saturday",
        "group" : "pro",
        "division" : "Women's",
        "level" : "Pro"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58ec60188cc818505fb75ad3"),
        "event" : "Men's Open",
        "day" : "Saturday",
        "group" : "pro",
        "division" : "Men's",
        "level" : "Pro"
}
```

I'd like to reorganize it and do counts returning something like this:

```
[ {_id: { day: "Saturday", group: "nonpro" },
  count: 3,
  divisions: [
    { division: "Men's",
      count: 2,
      levels: [ 
          { level: "BB", count: 1 },
          { level: "B", count: 1 }]
    },
    { division: "Women's",
      count: 1,
      levels: [ 
          { level: "BB", count: 1 }]
    }
 },
{_id: { day: "Saturday", group: "pro" },
  count: 2,
  divisions: [
    { division: "Men's",
      count: 1,
      levels: [ 
          { level: "Pro", count: 1 }
    },
    { division: "Women's",
      count: 1,
      levels: [ 
          { level: "Pro", count: 1 }]
    }
 },
{_id: { day: "Sunday", group: "nonpro" },
  count: 1,
  divisions: [
    { division: "Coed",
      count: 1,
      levels: [ 
          { level: "BB", count: 1 }
    }
 }]
```

I know I should be using the aggregate() function, but am having a hard time making it work with the count.  Here is what my aggregate looks like so far:

```
Registration
   .aggregate( 
  { $group: { 
      _id:   { day: "$day", group: "$group" }, 
      events: { $addToSet: { division: "$division", level: "$level"} },
      total: { $sum: 1}
    } 
  })
```

This returns the total registrations per day/group combination, but if I try adding total: {$sum: 1} to the events set, I just get 1 (which makes sense).  Is there a way to make this work in one database call, or do I need to do it separately for each level of grouping I need counts for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially need 3 levels of **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline stages. The first one will group the documents by all four keys i.e. `day`, `group`, `division` and `level`. Aggregate the counts for the group
which will be the counts for the `level`.

The preceding group will take three keys i.e. `day`, `group` and `division` and the aggregate count will sum the previous group counts as well as creating the `levels` array.

The last group will be the `day` and `group` keys + the `divisions` list embedded with the results from the previous group.

Consider running the following pipeline for the expected results:

```
Registration.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "day": "$day", 
                "group": "$group",
                "division": "$division",
                "level": "$level"
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "day": "$_id.day", 
                "group": "$_id.group",
                "division": "$_id.division"                
            },
            "count": { "$sum": "$count" },
            "levels": {
                "$push": {
                    "level": "$_id.level",
                    "count": "$count"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "day": "$_id.day", 
                "group": "$_id.group"             
            },
            "count": { "$sum": "$count" },
            "divisions": {
                "$push": {
                    "division": "$_id.division",
                    "count": "$count",
                    "levels": "$levels"
                }
            }
        }
    }
], (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));
})
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "day" : "Saturday",
        "group" : "nonpro"
    },
    "count" : 3,
    "divisions" : [ 
        {
            "division" : "Women's",
            "count" : 1,
            "levels" : [ 
                {
                    "level" : "BB",
                    "count" : 1
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "division" : "Men's",
            "count" : 2,
            "levels" : [ 
                {
                    "level" : "BB",
                    "count" : 1
                }, 
                {
                    "level" : "B",
                    "count" : 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "day" : "Saturday",
        "group" : "pro"
    },
    "count" : 2,
    "divisions" : [ 
        {
            "division" : "Women's",
            "count" : 1,
            "levels" : [ 
                {
                    "level" : "Pro",
                    "count" : 1
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "division" : "Men's",
            "count" : 1,
            "levels" : [ 
                {
                    "level" : "Pro",
                    "count" : 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "day" : "Sunday",
        "group" : "nonpro"
    },
    "count" : 1,
    "divisions" : [ 
        {
            "division" : "Coed",
            "count" : 1,
            "levels" : [ 
                {
                    "level" : "BB",
                    "count" : 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: My hero!!!  That works EXACTLY how I needed.  The quotes around $group and "_id" matter, which I don't quite get, but i'll go with it!